# Why wont my threejs model rotate on its own?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I currently have a New Jersey d3js map. A 3D map is created out of a topo.json.

I'm trying to find a way to make my map rotate on a fixed axis where I choose to make it appear, but instead, it decides to go over the scene. Scrolling makes it go around a globe instead of just rotating on itself. I've seen a lot of answers in SO and videos about examples that work perfectly out of the box like I'm expecting my model to do, but it just simply decides to scroll around like a globe.

It makes sense to set up a pivot and rotate around it, but I'm stuck figuring out how to make it work.

```
    var pivot = new THREE.Object3D();
    pivot.position.set(0,0,0);
    pivot.rotation.set(0,0,0);
    scene.add(pivot);
```

This is my current map.

Repository: https://github.com/max-benzait/d3js-new-jersey

Github Page: https://max-benzait.github.io/d3js-new-jersey/

It rotates as if it was going around a globe, and I'm looking to make it scroll like in this example.

```js
var camera, scene, renderer, mesh;
var local = false;

init();
animate();

function init() {
        // Camera setup
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 10 );
    camera.position.set( 1, 2, - 2 );
    
    // Scene setup
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    camera.lookAt( scene.position );

        // Cube Setup
    var geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 0.5, 0.5, 0.5 );
    var material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    mesh.position.set(0.5,0.5,0.5);
    // Note: Until the mesh is rotated, global and local rotation are the same
    mesh.rotation.y = 0.5;
    scene.add( mesh );
    
    // Add grid and axes
    scene.add( new THREE.GridHelper( 4, 10 ) );
    scene.add( new THREE.AxesHelper() );

        // Add renderer
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    
    // Create rotation toggle button
    var button = document.createElement("button");
    button.innerText = "Local Rotation Off";
    button.onclick = () => {
      local = !local
      if (local) button.innerText = "Local Rotation On";
      else button.innerText = "Local Rotation Off";
    };
    document.body.appendChild(button);
    

}

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    
    // This is GLOBAL
    if (!local) mesh.rotation.x += 0.03;
    // This is LOCAL
    else mesh.rotateX(0.03);
    
    renderer.render( scene, camera );

}
```

```css
body {
      margin: 0;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/build/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It looks like you're using [trackball controls](https://threejs.org/examples/#misc_controls_trackball), which is pretty unpredictable because it has 3 degrees of freedom and can turn upside down if you drag in circles. I recommend you use [orbit controls](https://threejs.org/examples/#misc_controls_orbit) which always keep up pointing up.

Comment: @Marquizzo how can I export this to my current project, Im struggling to do it, Im not using any kind of framework, just plain html, css and js

Comment: Found this https://unpkg.com/browse/three@0.132.0/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js
but it imports with a lot of errors

Comment: First add the `<script>` [with the core three.js](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.142.0/build/three.min.js), then add the script [with OrbitControls](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.142.0/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js).